# Display a warning message before leaving site to link

Tags: html, asp-classic, lightbox, lightbox2

I need to be able to have a popup, preferably like a lightbox that displays an html message when a user clicks a link.  The popup will populate the screen and the user will have to click "OK" after reading the message.  How can this be done using lightbox?  I'd rather avoid using a boring prompt as its much less attractive.

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it in lightbox, but as far as I can tell it's not quite what lightbox was intended for. You may want to consider a more generic "modal" type of solution. A common one is [jQuery UI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Another common one is [Bootstrap's modal solution](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).